# How to send an email from localhost?

Tags: node.js, email, server, localhost, host

I've had a look online and apparently with Node.js I could simply use the sendmail function from the sendmail library, but it did not work!

Here's what I've done after installing (npm i sendmail) sendmail libr.

```
import sendmail from 'sendmail';

sendmail({
    from: 'my@domain.com',
    to: 'test@qq.com',
    subject: 'test sendmail'
});
```

What am I missing, why it is not working?

I tried calling this function but emails have never been sent